# Return a type Array with TyepORM

Tags: graphql, typeorm

I am using typeorm for the first time. I am creating a User - Profile one-to-one relationship.
When I try to query the `profiles`, I get the error `Cannot return null for non-nullable field Profile.firstName`.

**My user entity**

```
@ObjectType()
@Entity("users")
export class User extends BaseEntity{

    @Field()
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn("uuid")
    id: string;

    @Field()
    @OneToOne(() => Profile, profile => profile.user) 
    @JoinColumn()
    profile: Profile;

    @Field()
    @Column({ nullable: true }) 
    profileId: string;

}
```

**My profile entity:**

```
@ObjectType()
@Entity("profile")
export class Profile extends BaseEntity{

    @Field()
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn("uuid")
    id: string;

    @OneToOne(() => User, user => user.profile)
    user: User;
}
```

**My Profiles Resolver Query**

```
@Resolver()
export class ProfileResolver {

  @Query(() => Profile)
  async profiles(
  ) {
    const profiles = await Profile.find()
    console.log("Profiles", profiles) // This contains the right data
    return profiles
  }
}
```

When I register a user for the first time, I make sure to first create a Profile, then attach it to the user.

**My Register Mutation when I create a user**

```
  @Mutation(() => Boolean)
  async register(
    @Arg('email') email: string,
    @Arg('password') password: string
  ) {
      const hashedPassword = await hash(password, 12)
      const profile: Profile = Profile.create()
      await profile.save()
      const user: User =  User.create({
        email,
        password: hashedPassword,
        profileId: profile.id,
        profile: profile
      })
      console.log(user) // It contains the user with a relative profile
```

I also tried to add the field here:

```
const profile: Profile = Profile.create({firstName: "test})
```

but I always get the error:

```
Cannot return null for non-nullable field Profile.firstName
```

when I run my query:

```
query{
  profiles{
    firstName
  }
}
```

I check other similar issue but I did not manage to solve it

Comment: Your `profiles` field is typed to return a single `Profile`, but you are returning an array of them inside your resolver. There is no `firstName` property on the array, so the `firstName` field cannot resolve correctly. Either change the type for your field or return a single Profile object inside your resolver.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I see my mistake, if I do `return[0]` the code works. However, I would like to return all the Profiles. I guess I have to change this line `@Query(() => Profile)` but how do I specify that I want an array of `Profile` and not just one?

Comment: I see, I should do something like: `@Query(() => [Profile])`, basically wrapping Profile in square brackets.